# Glassfish: Serve a page in French to a French user and a page in English to not French users

Tags: glassfish

I am developing a JavaEE web app using Glassfish as server. I want to serve the pages in French to all the users that live in a French spoken country and in English to the rest of the users.

Could you tell me how to do this? Does it have relation with the browser settings language or with the IP from which you are requesting the page?

Comment: *I want to serve the pages in French to all the users that live in a French spoken country* - that's going to really annoy people who live in French speaking countries and set their browser to request English language content (using the `Accept-Language` HTTP header: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php )

Comment: You are right. I will try to learn about it. Thank you